# multi checkbox on input javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I click on Select, a box opens and we select many options, including father and child.When options are selected
After selection, immediately display the ID numbers on the input. When we click OK, the box will be hidden. I want each of the boxes to be done separately in the input .This is My Html:

```
<button class="btn-select">Select one ...</button>
<div class="box" style="display:none">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1">Check Box 1
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="2">Check Box 2
<input type="text" class="input input-1" value="">
<button class="btn-ok">Ok</button>
</div>
<button class="btn-select">Select Two (Father/Children) ...</button>
<div class="box" style="display:none">
<ul class="father">
<li>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1">Part 1
<ul class="children">
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="5">Check Box 5</li>
</ul></li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="2">Part 2
<ul class="children">
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="7">Check Box 7</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="8">Check Box 8</li>                        
</ul></li></ul>
<input type="text" class="input input-2" value="">
<button class="btn-ok">Ok</button>
</div>
.
...Select Three...
..Select Four..
..
.
```

This is My JS (Children and Father):

```
handleChildren = function() {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    var $checkboxChildren = $checkbox.parent();
    $checkboxChildren.each(function() {
      if ($checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        $(this).prop("checked", "checked");
      } else {
        $(this).removeProp("checked");
      }
    });
};
handleParents = function(current) {
    var $parent = $(current).closest(".children").closest("li").find("> input[type=checkbox]");
    if ($parent.parent().find(".children input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0) {
      $parent.prop("checked", "checked");
    } else {
      $parent.removeProp("checked");
    }
    handleParents($parent);
}
$("ul.father").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    $(input).on("click", handleChildren);
    $(input).on("click", function() {
        handleParents(this);
    });
});
```

This is My JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-ok', function(){
    $('.box').hide()
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn-select', function(){
    $('.box').hide()
    $(this).next().show();
});
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    var text = "";
    $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        text += $(this).val() + ",";
    });
    text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
    $(this).next().val(text);
});
```

Now an error is shown by the console that says:

```
    Uncaught InternalError: too much recursion
    closest file:///var/www/html/jquey.js:1
```

Comment: Your `handleParents` calls itself unconditionally.

Comment: @morganney How? Can you modify the code?

Comment: Identify a base case and stop the recursion then.

Comment: @morganney I don't know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **handleParents** calls itself unconditionally.

Comment: A little bit more explanation would be great here. Like different possible ways that the above method invocation can be made conditional